# Is DefaultEventExecutor shared between Channels

Tags: netty

In the code below I introduced a DefaultEventExecutor where the actual Database inserting is done. I am in doubt if this is really the right way to go because there will be as much DefaultEventExecutors as Channels. Can someone help me on this?

```
public class SocketChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.my.snapshot");
public ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

public SocketChannelInitializer(ComboPooledDataSource cpds) {
    this.cpds = cpds;

}


@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("New SocketChannel connection from " + ch.remoteAddress());

    }

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    EventExecutor e1 = new DefaultEventExecutor();
    // and then business logic.

    pipeline.addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(200));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyPacketHeaderDecoder());

    /**
     * Inserting in DB happens in single Thread (e1)
     *
     */
    pipeline.addLast(e1, "logic", new PacketDatabaseHandler(cpds));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create one DefaultEventExecutorGroup instance and use the same instance in your initChannel(....) method. Otherwise it makes no sense as you will end up with as many threads as Channel.s

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.

Comment: I now have **one**  DefaultEventExecutorGroup(3) instance or the channels. With `jstack` I noticed these 3 threads are in a WAITING state. Are the used in a round-robin manner?